# Multiple .war files in a single IBM MobileFirst Server 6.3?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How does MobileFirst Server update a single WAR file?  does it update the existing or add with new version? can we have multiple war files with same application versions?

Comment: Can you better explain what do you mean by "same application versions"?

Answer (score 0):

In an IBM MobileFirst Development environment (= Eclipse Studio plug-in or CLI tool), after any change made to files that reside in the your-project\server folder, an updated .war file is generated for you and is automatically being re-deployed to the server. You could say that the existing .war file is replaced with the new .war file.

In a QA/UAT/Production environment (= WebSphere Full profile/Liberty profile with IBM MobileFirst Server running on top of it), you as the person who administers the application server must re-deploy the updated .war file by either manually replacing the file or by using the IBM-provided Ant task scripts. As in the development environment, this action also replaces the existing .war with the new .war file.

A MobileFirst Server is able to run multiple projects (.war files) at the same time.

It is not clear from the question what do you mean by "can we have multiple war files with same application versions?"

If you mean multiple .war files of the same project, each being an exact replica of the other - it sounds useless to me, but as long as each .war file is given a different context root in the server.xml file, you should be able to do that.

If that is not what you mean, well, take the time to better explain yourself.
Before that, read the documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html

Comment: application version I mean .wlapp files version e.g v1.0.0 is running on initial war file then we change the server files and updated war file so in this case WL server will update the existing war file or will create another war file with different version

Comment: Each project you create in Studio has its own .war file and its own .wlapp files.